# Comparing two files via MD5 hash on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

Comparing two files via MD5 hash on Amazon S3 using python - can it be done? should i use boto ot boto3?

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 has a built-in checksum called ETag.

You can use either boto or boto3.

Below documentation covers in detail,

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/

**CLI:**

> aws s3api head-object --bucket md5testbucket --key fileupload.txt

**boto 3:**

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
response = client.head_object(Bubket='md5testbucket',Key='fileupload.txt')
```

**boto:**

http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html

class boto.s3.key.Key(bucket=None, name=None)  -- Has Etag as its variable to represent its checksum.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can i use python?

Comment: @meitale The above reference uses python referencing libraries. Don't know where it was not clear.